# Issue with nested if stataments, expected ; but else found

Tags: scala

I am taking an intro to CS class at my University and we are doing an assignment that has us fix some code. I have fixed most of the errors, however cannot seem to see why this one is occuring. Here is my source code:

```
import scala.io.StdIn._

println("Does you character have a hat?")
var answer = readLine()
val correctOne = (answer == "y")

if (correctOne) {
    println("Does you character have ears?")
    answer = readLine()
    val correctTwo = (answer == "y")

    if (correctTwo) {
        println("Your character is Jason.") 
    }
    else {
        println("Your character is Opus.")
    }
else {
    println("Does you character have three eyes?")
    answer = readLine()
    val correctThree = (answer == "y")
    }
    if (correctThree) {
        println("You character is Gina.")
    }
    else {
        println("You character is Albert.")
    }

}
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\School\CSC10101\LAB\Lab6\fix.scala:24: error: ';' expected but 'else' found.
else {
^
one error found
```

I know this fix is probably very easy, but I cannot seem to see it. Any help/explanation is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little indentation helps:

```
import scala.io.StdIn._

println("Does you character have a hat?")
var answer = readLine()
val correctOne = (answer == "y")

if (correctOne) {
  println("Does you character have ears?")
  answer = readLine()
  val correctTwo = (answer == "y")

  if (correctTwo) {
    println("Your character is Jason.") 
  } else {
    println("Your character is Opus.")
  }
} else { // missing closing `}` in this line
  println("Does you character have three eyes?")
  answer = readLine()
  val correctThree = (answer == "y")

  // one `}` too much here

  if (correctThree) {
    println("You character is Gina.")
  } else {
    println("You character is Albert.")
  }
}
```

Is it some kind of new fashion to write `else` at the beginning of the new line recently?...

And don't indent by four spaces, [otherwise you will be paid less](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/) ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your intent correctly, you're both missing an ending brace `}` and including an extraneous `}`:

```
import scala.io.StdIn._

println("Does you character have a hat?")
var answer = readLine()
val correctOne = (answer == "y")

if (correctOne) {
  println("Does you character have ears?")
  answer = readLine()
  val correctTwo = (answer == "y")

  if (correctTwo) {
    println("Your character is Jason.") 
  } else {
    println("Your character is Opus.")
  }
} else { // --> added } on this line
  println("Does you character have three eyes?")
  answer = readLine()
  val correctThree = (answer == "y")
  // } --> you don't need this }
  if (correctThree) {
    println("You character is Gina.")
  } else {
    println("You character is Albert.")
  }
}
```